# Download Image from URL/Link in the CSV in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a CSV list which contains URL/Link of some image.

So I had tried this below code;

```
if (($handle = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

    fgetcsv($handle); 
    $num = count($data);

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
       $col[$c] = $data[$c];
    }
    col1 = $col[0];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($col1); $i++){
      if ( !$col1[$i] == null){  
          echo $col1[$i]. ",<br>";   
          file_put_contents("images/img.jpg", $elements[$i] . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
      }
   }
 }
 fclose($handle);
}
```

the code is working, but it's replacing the image at the end of execution I'm getting only one pic which's Last row of csv & Getting error `Max_execution` time.

Comment: have you tried google

Comment: Yes I had tried Googling..bt then also i'm not getting what I'm lookin for..!!

Comment: You've got a few problems there. First of all, `fgetcsv` gets a single row from the CSV, not the entire spreadsheet, so you need to keep calling it. Second you are writing `$elements[$i]` to the CSV, but you probably mean `$col1[$i]`. Third, you just keep appending text to the same `images/img.jpg` file over and over again, not actually getting the images. Do you mean maybe to go off and download the images and save them to unique files?

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the CSV file looks like?

Comment: My csv has only 1 coumn which contains Urls;
For ex; http:///www.websitename.com/images/image.jpg

Comment: 1. what is `$data` ? 2. fgetcsv() read 1 line! if it has single column, it does not matter, still read a single line..., and you loop through the single value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

```
$handle      = fopen($csv_file, "r");
$destination = 'images/';

if ($handle) {
    while ($columns = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        foreach ($columns as $imageUrl) {
            if (!empty($imageUrl)) {
                file_put_contents(
                    $destination . basename($imageUrl),
                    file_get_contents($imageUrl)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What it does is open the CVS, loops through it, row at a time, checks that the image URL isn't empty, downloads it and puts it into your directory. You of course need to make sure that PHP has the rights to write to that directory. The code also doesn't handle conflicts in the naming of images, so a further improvement would be to add some clash detection and append a counter before the suffix.

Comment: Could've sworn `file_exists` worked with URLs, but turns out I was going nuts. Anyway, just take that clause out and it should work. (answer updated)